# How to calculate the average Rating from the Extended Comment WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to calculate the average rating of the comment and place that value as a rating star at other page. For example. If the average rating value is "3 star". I want to print that value as "3 star image" and place that image at the another page. I asked this question in many site but not getting any answer. Please help me somebody

This is the URL

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/08/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/

```
$plugin_url_path = WP_PLUGIN_URL;

if( $commenttitle = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'title', true ) ) {
    $commenttitle = '<strong>' . esc_attr( $commenttitle ) . '</strong><br/>';
    $text = $commenttitle . $text;
} 

if( $commentrating = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true ) ) {
    $commentrating = '<p class="comment-rating">    <img src="'. $plugin_url_path .
    '/ExtendComment/images/'. $commentrating . 'star.gif"/><br/>Rating: <strong>'. $commentrating .' / 5</strong></p>';
    $text = $text . $commentrating;
    return $text;       
} else {
    return $text;       
}
```

}

Comment: Not showing full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found one solution for this that gives the average rating. Please add the following function in extendcomment.php

```
function average_rating() {
global $wpdb;
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$ratings = $wpdb->get_results("

    SELECT $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value
    FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->comments on $wpdb->comments.comment_id=$wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id
    WHERE $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key='rating' 
    AND $wpdb->comments.comment_post_id=$post_id 
    AND $wpdb->comments.comment_approved =1

    ");
$counter = 0;
$average_rating = 0;    
if ($ratings) {
    foreach ($ratings as $rating) {
        $average_rating = $average_rating + $rating->meta_value;
        $counter++;
    } 
    //round the average to the nearast 1/2 point
    return (round(($average_rating/$counter)*2,0)/2);  
} else {
    //no ratings
    return 'no rating';
}
```

}

Call the function with "" which will give the numerical average. For displaying average as image refer the "function modify_comment( $text )".

Comment: not working, I got some error.